# TOA distance resolution

Tags: wave

As far as I could understand, TOA systems, abstractly, work by measuring the time it took the wave to transfer from a transmitter to a receiver and multiplying it by the speed of the wave in the medium.

If the the wave travels at the speed of light ~3 x 10<sup>8</sup> m/s, the smallest distance can be measured is around 0.3 m if the system smallest measured tick is 1 ns.

So, with a system capable of only measuring nanosecond ticks, the best theoretical resolution that can be achieved is ~0.3 m.

Is my previous conclusion correct? If not, why?

**Edit:**

Synchronization is beyond my question scope. You may consider that everything is perfectly synchronized.

Comment: By down-converting with a MIXER, to an intermediate-frequency, the spacing of the zero-crossings can be greatly expanded. Additionally, circuits exist to store charge during corresponding edges of synchronous but delayed waveforms; the system then will measure the voltage of the stored charge as linear indicator of timing shift.

Comment: How would you determine the timestamp of the sent signal?

Comment: Yes---ambiguity must be resolved. Have never implemented such a system.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Synchronization is, ofcourse, a big issue. However, it is beyond the scope of my question.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Thanks! actually I am not from an EE background so I could not understand your comment properly. what I could understand that  with storing the signal (or period of it) analogy in somehow, it is possible to measure sub-tick delay in the retrieved signal which means 1 Nanosecond is not the limit in my example. Did I understand correctly? Thanks again for your comment!

Comment: Hewlett Packard sold a Time_Frequency Measurement Counter in the 1960s, that used 2N5179 transistors (1.5GHz devices) to steer currents to and from a capacitor as digital edges arrived from different signals. The system had 10MHz reference clock (100,000 picoseconds period) yet provided 100 picoseconds time resolution, using charge storage and then charge (voltage) quantization.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Thank you very much for the example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a free lunch. So no, you can't have higher resolution than what you've been given. However, there are a few points to ponder:

1. Practically speaking you *can* upsample the capture and thus gain resolution, because any system has a little jitter and/or is asynchronous, and we'll assume you took multiple measurements. So you've effectively added more samples at different timing positions.
2. If the TOAs are "absolute" (that is, you know the transmit time), then the probability distribution for one TOA is a hollow sphere around the receiver with a diameter of the distance calculated. The intersection of multiple spheres from multiple receivers is used to resolve the transmitter's position, and you gain resolution according to how many spheres there are, because you are effectively adding more samples.
3. If the transmit time is not known, then pairs of TOAs to multiple receivers can be used to generate TDOAs (time difference of arrival). A TDOA produces a hyperboloid sheet of probability distribution between the receivers. The intersection of multiple sheets is used to resolve the transmitter's position, and you gain resolution according to how many sheets there are, because you are effectively adding more samples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer!